# how we can move selected area in Imgareaselect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new in jquery. I created a "imgareaselect" . and it was successfully created. but i have problem in moving selected portion.pls help me out...
my code is:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/imgareaselect-default.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.imgareaselect.pack.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
   $('#ferret').imgAreaSelect({ maxWidth: 200, maxHeight: 150, handles: true });
   });
   ;
 function preview(img, selection) {
    var scaleX = 100 / (selection.width || 1);
    var scaleY = 100 / (selection.height || 1);
    $('#ferret + div > img').css({
        width: Math.round(scaleX * 400) + 'px',
        height: Math.round(scaleY * 300) + 'px',
        marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(scaleX * selection.x1) + 'px',
        marginTop: '-' + Math.round(scaleY * selection.y1) + 'px'
    });
   }

   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('<div><img src="http://jotform.org/demo/jquery-image-area-select-plugin/images/sweet-dogs.jpg" style="position: relative;" /><div>')
       .css({
            float: 'right',
            position: 'relative',
            overflow: 'hidden',
            width: '100px',
            height: '100px'
        })
        .insertAfter($('#ferret'));

    $('#ferret').imgAreaSelect({ aspectRatio: '1:1', onSelectChange: preview });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

   <img src="http://jotform.org/demo/jquery-image-area-select-plugin/images/sweet-dogs.jpg" id="ferret" style="height:200px;width:300px;">



</body>
```

I am able to create Imgareaselet .seleced image showing in new div but i have problem in moving selected area.I hope you understand my question.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: I gave you all Code in my Question . jquery and html  . and my question is when i select my image portion its showing in div but when i want to move my selected image or drag selected image .  Its not working.

Comment: Why are you initializing the plugin twice on the same selector?

Comment: Sorry but pls can you explain what you want to say.

Comment: You have 2 `$(document).ready(function(){ $('#ferret').imgAreaSelect...`. why?

Comment: hello Rob M , I have one more question that is if i want to select image according to pixels like 145X190 etc not with ratio then how we can select.....